# Como eu faço para alinhar ao centro usando html5 e css3 um bloco com 4 vídeos embedados do YouTube?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando alinhar ao centro um bloco de vídeos embedados do YouTube (2 em cima e 2 em baixo) de forma que o bloco todo saia do alinhamento esquerdo (como é default ao embedar) e fique centralizado.

Já tentei colocar 2 em vídeos em divs separadas, já tentei criar uma única div e centralizar via css no head, mas todos os vídeos ficam alinhados em modo de coluna e não de bloco.

O código atual está mais ou menos

Desafio de vídeo

```
<style>
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .bloco1{
    margin-left: 100;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;

    }

    .bloco2{
    margin-left: 500;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;

    }
</style>
```

```
<h1>Vídeos legais para assistir</h1>

 <div class="bloco1">   
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q4aGQTYYRGA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J1ByEAYWLM8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

<div class="bloco2"> 
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D4hAVemuQXY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vLrfjqgLbNU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Agradeço a ajuda desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar uma outra div envolvendo esses dois blocos e organizar eles usando flexbox, segue estrutura html:

```
      <div class="bloco-videos">

        <div class="bloco">
          <iframe width="50%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q4aGQTYYRGA"
            title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
          <iframe width="50%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J1ByEAYWLM8"
            title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="bloco">
          <iframe width="50%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D4hAVemuQXY"
            title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>

          </iframe>
          <iframe width="50%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vLrfjqgLbNU"
            title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen>

          </iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Agora no css, você pode fazer assim:

```
.bloco-videos {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.bloco {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```